# How to configure iSCSI Redirection on either Linux or Windows?

Tags: scsi, iscsi

I am trying to set up an **iSCSI redirection** environmnt.

First I tried with Windows Server 2012 following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84K-xYXFkzU). But it seems the Windows Server 2012 doesn't provide the iSCSI redirection feature.

Then I found this [comparison](http://scst.sourceforge.net/comparison.html) about iSCSI tools on Linux. It claims the [tgt](http://stgt.sourceforge.net/) supports redirection. But so far I haven't tried it out on Unbuntu.

Does anyone ever used this feature? Be it Linux or Windows.